# httpbeat package not installed on centos 7

Tags: centos, centos7, rpm, yum

I downloaded the file from:
https://github.com/christiangalsterer/httpbeat/releases
`httpbeat-4.0.0-x86_64.rpm`

and tried to install it via:
`sudo yum localinstall httpbeat-4.0.0-x86_64.rpm`

But i don't see that it is installed by commands:

```
[k@f httpbeat]$ rpm -ql httpbeat-4.0.0-x86_64.rpm
package httpbeat-4.0.0-x86_64.rpm is not installed

[k@f httpbeat]$ sudo yum install httpbeat-4.0.0-x86_64.rpm
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Examining httpbeat-4.0.0-x86_64.rpm: httpbeat-5.2.1_SNAPSHOT-1.x86_64
httpbeat-4.0.0-x86_64.rpm: does not update installed package.
Error: Nothing to do

[k@f httpbeat]$ rpm -qi httpbeat-4.0.0-x86_64.rpm
package httpbeat-4.0.0-x86_64.rpm is not installed


[k@f httpbeat]$ sudo rpm -i httpbeat-4.0.0-x86_64.rpm
        package httpbeat-5.2.1_SNAPSHOT-1.x86_64 is already installed

[k@f httpbeat]$ rpm -qi httpbeat-4.0.0-x86_64.rpm
package httpbeat-4.0.0-x86_64.rpm is not installed


[k@f httpbeat]$ sudo yum remove httpbeat-4.0.0-x86_64.rpm
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
No Match for argument: httpbeat-4.0.0-x86_64.rpm
No Packages marked for removal

[k@f httpbeat]$ sudo yum install httpbeat-4.0.0-x86_64.rpm
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Examining httpbeat-4.0.0-x86_64.rpm: httpbeat-5.2.1_SNAPSHOT-1.x86_64
httpbeat-4.0.0-x86_64.rpm: does not update installed package.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Sometimes it tells me that it is `already installed`, other times that is not - which is true and how can i install it successfully?

**Edit**:

```
[k@f httpbeat]$ yum remove httpbeat-4.0.0-x86_64
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
You need to be root to perform this command.
[k@f httpbeat]$ sudo yum remove httpbeat-4.0.0-x86_64
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
No Match for argument: httpbeat-4.0.0-x86_64
No Packages marked for removal

rpm -ql httpbeat-4.0.0-x86_64
package httpbeat-4.0.0-x86_64 is not installed
```

Answer (score 0):

This command is wrong:

```
$ rpm -ql httpbeat-4.0.0-x86_64.rpm
```

`rpm` command looks for the package name in the database, and it doesn't have `.rpm` extension. Instead, do this after using `yum localinstall`

```
$ rpm -ql httpbeat-4.0.0-x86_64
```

Same thing for the `yum remove`. After installation it uses `rpmdb`,

```
$ yum remove httpbeat-4.0.0-x86_64
```

Comment: I edited the question. I want to install successfully this rpm not only delete it.  Sth is wrong with it i think after `yum localinstall ` fileName.rpm

Comment: Like I said in my answer, your command `rpm -ql <package>.rpm` is wrong. It needs to be `rpm -ql <package>`, no `.rpm`

Comment: Yes i know - that's why i edited the question - check it out for output of your suggest command

Comment: How do you know it is installed before you try to remove it ? I don't see that in your edited question. Also you are using `yum install` for a locally downloaded package, that's not going to work.

Comment: To be excact i think that i installed it by `sudo yum localinstall httpbeat-4.0.0-x86_64.rpm`